# import excel file to mysql with laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to import excel file to mysql. Excel file has 8 columns. Everything is going well except date column. Not whole column but some fields showing wrong date i.e excel date is `30-09-2015` after importing its became `1900-01-30`, `13-09-2015` after importing its became `1900-01-13`. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: which package are you using for excel file importing?

Comment: i'm using maatwebsite.

Comment: Not all dates going wrong but few are going to 1900 .

Comment: Probably you have to include some code. If you read out the columns as text, what does it show?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `setColumnFormat`?

I think it is caused by the date format `13-09-2015` which is not a valid date in the format `mm-dd-yyyy`, so suggest you set the column format to `dd-mm-yyyy`.

[Reference](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/export#format)

Comment: i have 100 entries in date column.75 entries are showing right dates but only 25 are being showing wrong.If there is some problem with setColumnFormat then all entries should be wrong.

Comment: are the wrong date all begins with number greater than 12? @Shahid